# Recovering Files from SD Card

Tags: filesystem, sd-card

I accidently moved my iMac with the SD card inserted and the card got bent, it cannot be read anymore. Not sure if it can be recovered. I was wondering if somehow the files are stored on the HD. I did not import the (RAW) files.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on *how* the SD card was damaged someone with some electronic skills *might* be able to straighten things out enough to get the files off of it. Possibly a phone repair shop? They might need to extract the memory chip circuitry from the damaged card and put it in another card, or even just re-solder some leads. Impossible to tell without actually examining the card in person

If, however, the actual memory chip in the card was damaged, you are out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

I you just put the SD are in the reader, the system will only mount the device.

If you did not import the files, they will not be present on your hard drive.